# How do I print dependent variable with their corresponding coefficient?

Tags: python

I have the following `feature_names`:
['x' 'y' 'x^2' 'x y' 'y^2']
and `true_coefs`: [[ 1  2  3  4 5]].

I'm trying to print the two in a format that show each dependent variable with their corresponding coefficient.

I tried using `print(dict(zip(feature_names, true_coefs)))`, however my output comes out as {'x': array([ 1,  2,  3,  4, 5])}. How am I able to adjust the code so that it comes out as x:1, y:2, x^2:3, xy:4, and y^2:5?

Comment: Hint: as shown, one is a list of five items, and one is a list of one item, which is a list of five items.  The data structures are not the same.

Answer (score 1):

IF you mean you have two list and first list have 5 items and the second list just have one item you can use this code

```
a=['x' ,'y' ,'x^2', 'x y', 'y^2']
b=["12345"]
for i,j in enumerate (a):
    print(j,":",b[0][i],",")
```

and out put be like that:
x : 1 ,
y : 2 ,
x^2 : 3 ,
x y : 4 ,
y^2 : 5 ,